# Attempting To Override Pager - Type Error

Tags: magento2, blocks

Right now, I'm simply attempting to override the Pager class.  Without changing anything within it, I've copied it into my module, and then specified the preference in the di:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" type="MyVendor\Core\Block\Html\Pager"/>
</config>
```

Problem is, after doing so, I run into a Type Error when creating an Item class:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Catalog\...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog...', array()) called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/ItemFactory.php:43]
#3 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\ItemFactory->create() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/AbstractFilter.php:236]
#4 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter->_createItem('Cut-Off Wheels', 1045, 15) called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/AbstractFilter.php:205]
#5 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter->_initItems() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/AbstractFilter.php:159]
#6 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter->getItems() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/AbstractFilter.php:148]
#7 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter->getItemsCount() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Category/AvailabilityFlag.php:33]
#8 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\AvailabilityFlag->canShowOptions(array(&Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category#0000000062560a0700000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062560e2500000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062561cb500000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062561d4000000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256144100000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256145000000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256145e00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Price#0000000062561cc900000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062561c3d00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062561c9700000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256065f00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062561c3200000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062561c3f00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062561c9b00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062561c1e00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062561c2800000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256073200000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256073100000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256069900000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256069d00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256070400000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256070f00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062560b0800000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062560b1100000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062560b1400000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062560b0d00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062560b7b00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062560b0600000000508c807a#)) called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Category/AvailabilityFlag.php:23]
#9 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\AvailabilityFlag->isEnabled(&Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\Interceptor#000000006256039000000000508c807a#, array(&Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category#0000000062560a0700000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062560e2500000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062561cb500000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062561d4000000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256144100000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256145000000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256145e00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Price#0000000062561cc900000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062561c3d00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062561c9700000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256065f00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062561c3200000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062561c3f00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062561c9b00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062561c1e00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062561c2800000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256073200000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256073100000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256069900000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256069d00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256070400000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#000000006256070f00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062560b0800000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062560b1100000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062560b1400000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062560b0d00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062560b7b00000000508c807a#, &Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#0000000062560b0600000000508c807a#)) called at [vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/Block/Navigation.php:110]
#10 Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation->canShowBlock() called at [vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/frontend/templates/layer/view.phtml:18]
#11 include('/vagrant/vendor/...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation#00000000625619d000000000508c807a#, '/vagrant/vendor/...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/vagrant/vendor/...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:668]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('catalog.leftnav') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:533]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('catalog.leftnav') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('catalog.leftnav') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('catalog.leftnav', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('catalog.leftnav', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('sidebar.main', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('sidebar.main') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('sidebar.main') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('sidebar.main', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('sidebar.main', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('div.sidebar.main', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('div.sidebar.main') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('div.sidebar.main') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('div.sidebar.main', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('div.sidebar.main', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#40 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#46 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#47 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#48 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#49 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#50 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:954]
#51 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#52 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#53 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#54 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', array(), array(array('layout-model-cac...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:494]
#55 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:258]
#56 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000062560b7100000000508c807a#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#57 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000062560b7100000000508c807a#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#58 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000062560b7100000000508c807a#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#59 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000062560b7100000000508c807a#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#60 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000062560b7100000000508c807a#), array(array('result-messages', 'result-builtin-c...', 'result-varnish-c...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:130]
#61 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000062560b7100000000508c807a#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:140]
#62 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#63 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:258]
#64 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#0000000062560a9c00000000508c807a#) called at [pub/index.php:40]
</pre>
```

Any ideas as to what is going on here?

Alright, I think I'm beginning to understand a little.  Item is injecting \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager, and throwing an error as my class doesn't match, even though I'm overriding it with the di preference.  Any way around this?

Comment: try to run setup upgrade , static content deploy , clear chache and then check

Answer (score 0):

In order to get past the Type Error, I had to change my Pager to extend the base Pager class as opposed to the base Template class as the original did.

Answer (score 0):

In **di.xml** use,

```
<preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" type="MyVendor\Core\Block\Html\Pager"/>
```

In **`MyVendor\Core\Block\Html\Pager`** use,

```
namespace MyVendor\Core\Block\Html;
```

Extend the class by using,

```
class Pager extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager
{
public function MyCustomFunction()

{
   return "working";

} 
}
```